# Bounce rate nearly 90% in Safari, why?

Tags: browser, google-analytics, safari

Our website has a bounce rate of nearly 90% in all Safari versions and around 70% in all other browsers.
I tested the site on almost safari versions and couldn't find a clear reason why this high bounce-rate percentage only existed in the safari browser. has anyone else faced this issue? any solutions?

Comment: Do you send any events besides the pageviews? Do these events, if any, work on Safari?

Comment: Thank you @MichelePisani for the comment. yes I send events and it works on safari